# Converting classes from python 3 to 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I found a code that defined this class in python 3:

```
class APF_Improved(APF):
    def __init__(self, start: (), goal: (), obstacles: [], k_att: float, k_rep: float, rr: float,
             step_size: float, max_iters: int, goal_threshold: float, is_plot=False):
        self.start = Vector2d(start[0], start[1])
        self.current_pos = Vector2d(start[0], start[1])
        self.goal = Vector2d(goal[0], goal[1])
        self.obstacles = [Vector2d(OB[0], OB[1]) for OB in obstacles]
        self.k_att = k_att
        self.k_rep = k_rep
        self.rr = rr  # Repulsive force range
        self.step_size = step_size
        self.max_iters = max_iters
        self.iters = 0
        self.goal_threashold = goal_threshold
        self.path = list()
        self.is_path_plan_success = False
        self.is_plot = is_plot
        self.delta_t = 0.01
```

When I run this code in python 2.7 the following error shows up:

> File
>   "/home/Path_Plan-master/Artificial_Potential_Field/Improved_APF-1.py",
>   line 12
>       def **init**(self, start: (), goal: (), obstacles: [], k_att: float, k_rep: float, rr: float,
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Could anyone give me a hint about this? How can I find the equivalent syntax in python 2.7?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Do you have a extremely large legacy project that you can't just run 2to3 on or something?

Comment: Personally, I would opt to switch to python3, with python 2 going to be deprecated by next year. You would have to go line by line in your class to find the syntax errors in that class. Personally I don't know enough to correct everything, but is the indentation correct? line 2 is already wrong with indentation. The rest of the fields, you'd have to try each parameter. I can't tell off the bat. You could also try https://pypi.org/project/3to2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class definition uses [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), which are not supported in Python 2.7.

You can probably remove them without affecting the functionality of the code:

```
class APF_Improved(APF):
    def __init__(self, start, goal, obstacles, k_att, k_rep, rr,
             step_size, max_iters, goal_threshold, is_plot=False):
        ...
```